# JavaFx 3D does not run on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, 3d

When trying to run the *javaFX 3D demo on my Ubuntu 14.04 (Gallium 0.4 on AMD REDWOOD, Java JDK 8u5), I get the fellowing error message:

```
Executing /home/lehuythangit/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication2/dist/run869814863/JavaFXApplication2.jar using platform /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java
May 20, 2014 11:35:59 AM javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
May 20, 2014 11:35:59 AM javafx.scene.Scene$7 invalidated
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle's JDK or OpenJDK's JDK? Or are you using some other Java Runtime Environment?